# Is it possible to award the bounty to a comment owner?

Tags: discussion, comments, bounty

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty, **How is a bounty awarded?**:

> The bounty period lasts 7 days. **Bounties** must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. **Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty** to the answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)

What if my question was resolved by a comment and not by an answer?   Is it possible to award the bounty to the comment owner?

Should I ask the comment owner to add it as an answer and then award him the bounty?

Comment: No you can't reward a comment with a bounty. The rest is covered in this Q&A: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597)

Comment: Asking them to add an answer is certainly an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should I ask the comment owner to add it as an answer and then award him the bounty?

Yes, you should do exactly this.  Often, people will post a comment to confirm a solution they're not sure of.  Most people would be happy to convert that into an answer to receive a bounty for it :-)

Comment: Nice , i just wanted to confirm it's not against the rules.